# What are the different blows of the whistle of football (soccer) for a foul, start of game, end, ect

Tags: football

I am going to be playing football (soccer) with my friends, and I'm referee. I need to know what the different whistle blows. Please can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

As already stated the LoTG don't mention that, but there are a few guidelines.

- One long blow

  - any interruption you have to call (such as fouls, offside, etc)
  - kick-off
- One short blow

  - resume the game after previous interruption
- Two blows

  - Half time
- Three blows

  - End of the game
- Multiple short blows

  - Get attention (substitution, call a player to you to show a card, try to disperse a pack, etc.)

Comment: These are the most common ones I believe, and often used (at least) in Europe.

Answer (score 0):

The [Laws of the Game](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/the-referee/) do not specify the means in which the whistle should be blown, so you can do whatever you like (within reason); what is *far* more important is that you understand the Laws, and your communication with the players is clear.

It is probably worth reading the [body language, communication and whistle](https://www.theifab.com/laws/latest/guidelines/body-language-communication-and-whistle/) guideline which is attached to the Laws so that you understand the situations in which you are required to blow the whistle - and the situations you are not.